# Maximum over $2n$ real numbers

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

Let $\frac{1}{n}\leq a_1,...,a_m\leq 1$ and $0\leq b_1,...,b_m\leq 1$ be real numbers such that 
$$\sum_{i=1}^m a_i^2b_i=k.$$
Find the maximum of 
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^m b_i\right)^{k+1}\left(\prod_{i=1}^m a_i^{b_ia_i^2}\right).$$

I tried weighted AM-GM in many ways but I failed. It seems that if all $b_i=1$ then we get the maximum.